# Cognitive Computing vs Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: terminology, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Can anyone please tell me the difference between them?
A brief definition of Cognitive Computing would appreciated.

Also how does cognitive computing relate to neural networks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A brief definition would be:

> Cognitive computing is the simulation of human thought processes in a computerized model.

more detailed explanation:

> Cognitive computing involves self-learning systems that use data mining, pattern recognition and natural language processing to mimic the way the human brain works. The goal of cognitive computing is to create automated IT systems that are capable of solving problems without requiring human assistance.

Cognitive computing is used in A.I. applications. Therefore I think it can be concluded that Cognitive Computing is a subset of Artificial Intelligence.

Cognitive Computing systems may include the following ostensible characteristics:

1. Natural Language Processing
2. Machine Learning
3. Algorithms that learn and adapt
4. Vision-based sensing and image recognition
5. Spatial and contextual awareness
6. Reasoning and decision automation
7. Sophisticated pattern recognition
8. Neural Networks
9. Semantic Understanding
10. Noise Filtering
11. Common Sense
12. Robotic Control
13. Emotional Intelligence

So basically, you can say that a cognitive computing system might be trained by neural networks.

Sources:

1. http://www.cognitivecomputingforum.com/
2. http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/cognitive-computing